# rails でテーブルのカラム名を grep したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

全てのテーブルを対象にカラムでgrepしたいとき、どうしていますか？

Comment: 質問を編集してもう少し目的をはっきり出来ないでしょうか。やりたいことによって方法の方向性が変わってきますので。

Answer (score 1):

1. db/schema.rb に全てのtable定義があるので、そのファイルをgrep
2. 直接DBにいって各RDBMS実装に応じたやりかたでgrep

思い付くのはこれぐらいですね。

Answer (score 0):

用途がよく分からないので外しているかもですが、ActiveRecord を使っていて Ruby のコードで書くということなら以下の感じですかね？

```
all_col_names = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next if table.match(/\Aschema_migrations\Z/)
  next if table.match(/\Aar_internal_metadata\Z/)
  klass = table.singularize.camelize.constantize
  klass.column_names.each do|column_name|
    all_col_names[column_name] << table
  end
end

all_col_names['title'] # title カラムを持つテーブルの Array が取得できる
```

Rails 5.1.2 + sqlite3 で確認しました。